# Create own color ramps from attribute table based on unique column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, symbology, attribute-table

I have Four columns like MapCode R G B, I would like to create my own colour from the attribute table(R, G, B-Column) for Mapcode.

I would like to apply symbology based on MapCode values(which is unique) and I have the color Values (R, G, B,) as seprate Columns in the same table. how to create color ramps for unique map_code

MapCode, R, G, B

---

AB1C, 243, 255, 128

---

BB12, 124, 125, 120

---

[image]

Comment: Not really sure what you want to do. Can you explain a little further? To get a color from your columns use data defined override and an expression like `"R"||','||"G"||','||"B"||','||255`. May I ask what you want to do with python and plugins?

Comment: I would like to apply symbology based on MapCode values(which is unique) and I have the color Values (R, G, B,) as seprate Columns in the same table, is there any plugins or python code available to do that

Comment: You dont need plugins to do that. Data defined symbology definition is a core feature of QGIS. Possible using python too, but as I interpret your question, there is no need for it. Can you give an example how a symbol shall look like when MapCode is AB1C and how if MapCode is BB12?

Comment: can u please have a look on that pic so that it will be easy to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Layer Properties and the Symbology tab

Depending on the layer type just select a simple fill, or a simple line instead of a categorized symbol.

Next to the "Fill color" or "Stroke color" whatever you are wanting colored, and there is a drop down select next to it. Select `Edit...` from the drop down which will bring up the `Expression String Builder`

[image]

Put in this expression `color_rgb( "R","G","B")`

where "R" "G" and "B" represent the column names that contain your RGB values.

I added some random RGB values to a USA state layer and this was the result

[image: USA random assigned colors]

Comment: **Thanks**, @TJ Rockefeller., It works for me but still, I have problems while exporting for web(using qgis2web plugin) it takes only one colour not the classified colours everything shows a single colour. how do I rectify this problem?

Comment: @Gobinath Sorry to hear that this isn't working for export to the web. I don't have any experience with the qgis2web plugin, and you may need to ask another question specific to qgis2web.

Comment: Thank you. @TJ Rockefeller ... I'll rise one more question with detailed screenshots... Thank you very much